# Camera manipulating actor's heights? (Chris Bauer height? The Wire vs For All Mankind)

Tags: cinematography, the-wire

I've started watching [For All Mankind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_All_Mankind_(TV_series)) and was pleased to see [Chris Bauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Bauer) in a strong supporting role playing [Deke Slayton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deke_Slayton). I hadn't seen him in anything since he played [Frank Sobotka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Sobotka) in [The Wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wire)

In The Wire, "Frank Sobotka" is a short, stocky dock worker. In "For All Mankind", Bauer's "Deke Slayton" is at least 6 feet tall, thin and wiry,

Was he "acting short" in The Wire or is he "acting tall" in For All Mankind?

How films are shot definitely shift impressions of height, etc but I always thought it was done for the actor's vanity (Tom Cruise, Dustin Hoffman, Al Pacino), not for adding to the role.

Anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: I know that in Circle of Friends, Minnie Driver had to walk in a ditch to make Chris O'Donnell appear taller than he really was. I checked the IMDB Trivia pages for both The Wire and For All Mankind, but was unable to find anything similar. Bauer did wear a fat suit in The Wire: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0306414/trivia?item=tr2800548

Comment: @Raj -  Great trivia about the fat suit! Maybe greater "width" made him look shorter?